# AngularJS - ngmodel and input type button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have what is basically a radio type selection, but because I wanted it to look more like a selection grid I opted to make a input type button instead and triggering a function on click, but I have a problem. ng-model won't bind the value of the button I clicked to the controller part, and I know it works just fine as a radio button.

What's the quickest way to solve this? I'm assuming there's an easier way than to redefine the css of a radio button... Especially since it's all done except linking the value on click with the variable itself.

The section in question:

```
        <div class="aquipartners" id="aquipartnersID">               
            <input ng-repeat="partner in partners" align="center" type = 'button' class = "aquipartnernamebutton" id='aqui{{partner.name.PT}}' value='{{partner.name.PT}}' ng-model='newaquisubmission.part' onclick ='partnerselect()'>
            </input>
        </div>
```

And on the JS side:

```
    function partnerselect(){


        var scopepartnerbutton = $('#subtitleid').scope().newaquisubmission.part;

        alert(scopepartnerbutton);

        if(scopepartnerbutton !== ""){

            //the stuff I want to do, I added the if as a safeguard while I program everything
        }

    };
```

Comment: Use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: doesn't make sense. What are you expecting `ng-model` to do when it is different model than value? why is jQuery or `onclick` involved here?

Comment: Sorry, I want it to add the value of the button I clicked, value='{{partner.name.PT}}' to the controller variable on ng-model='newaquisubmission.part'

Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way...

Comment: Probably are. Not really clear what you are trying to do though

Comment: Use `ng-model="x[$index]"` inside `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @georgeawg said, use ng-click. make sure you have this on your controller:

```
$scope.partnerselect = partnerselect
```

and partnerselect should be declared like this:

```
function partnerselect(value) {
if($scope.newaquisubmission.part){
   $scope.newaquisubmission.part = value; //Assuming this is what you want to do..
}    
}
```

On your view:

```
    <div class="aquipartners" id="aquipartnersID">               
        <input ng-repeat="partner in partners" align="center" type = 'button' class = "aquipartnernamebutton" id='aqui{{partner.name.PT}}' value='{{partner.name.PT}}' ng-click ="partnerselect(partner.name.PT)">
        </input>
    </div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, though I ran into a relatively small problem, it couldn't find variable $scope. I managed to work around it by using the scope() method but I'm assuming this isn't the best approach. I probably have an error somewhere that triggers this, do you have any idea what it usually is? Thanks in advance

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I'm quite new to angular as well. It must be the way you code. Maybe you're doing it like this: module.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", myController]) while some declare it like this: module.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", function() {
//$scope.isAvailable = true }])

Comment: Better let the experts explain those stuff. Anyway, show some appreciation to my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar problem by using `(click)` instead of `onclick`